# Does any Mac app actually block Safari ads?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, adblock

Up until yesterday, I used AdBlock Plus to get rid of ads on Safari, in particular these annoying Gmail ones:

[image: Some annoying ads at the top of a Gmail inbox]

But yesterday, I installed MacOS Mojave and I guess it upgraded my Safari so that traditional extensions don't work. However, when I go to the Mac App Store, there don't seem to be any adblocking apps that users claim actually work. Do I just have to get used to seeing junk at the top of my inbox again?

Comment: You may need to wait a bit for the extension writers to catch up to the new Safari extension API. You could also make your desires known by posting to any official discussion boards for your favorite adblockers. It is more likely you'll find accurate info on whether or not they have plans for a new version there.

Comment: I have no ads showing. Which web site doe that for you.

Comment: I don't remember the exact process now, but you can absolutely re-enable the old type of extension, as long as it was installed from the official extensions gallery.

Answer (score 2):

I recently installed the Brave browser on my Macs - it is way faster than Safari and blocks most adds.

[Brave](https://brave.com/)

Comment: Why the down vote? Safari doesn’t block ads very well , Brave does. If you are going to downvote at least state why

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can block ads on Safari using [Adblock for Safari](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adblock-for-safari/id1402042596?mt=12); it's available on the App Store and compatible with macOS 10.12 or later, 64-bit processor.

Comment: It seems like around August or September 2018 some updates for Safari disabled extensions and then an option for ABP users was using the [app](https://adblockplus.org/category/adblock-plus-safari/) for macOS

Comment: I didn't test the Gmail example, but tested on Yahoo.com and the top banner was blocked! (macOS 10.12.6)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can go to (in Safari) preferences, extensions, and re-enable ABP after the update. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[1Blocker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1blocker/id1107421413) works well for me and is very configurable.